# Bodyparser is incorrectly parsing JSON?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, express

I'm using the body-parser NPM module with Express to parse json on my server, but for some reason, the JSON is showing up incorrectly on the server. Here is my server code:

```
...
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
...

app.route("/schedule")
    .get(function(req, res) {
        ... 
    })
    .post(function(req, res) {
        var schedule = req.body.schedule;

        console.log(req.body);

        if(schedule) {
            setSchedule(schedule);
            res.status(200).end();
        }
    });
```

And my client code:

```
var schedule = {
    entries: entries
};

var str = JSON.stringify(schedule);

console.log("Submitting schedule:",str);
post("/schedule", str)
    .then((res) => {
        this.completed(res.json);
    })
    .catch((res) => {
        this.failed(res.text);
    });
```

When I POST the data from the client, the client prints this:

```
Submitting schedule: {"entries":[1430014800000,1430055600000,1430104620000,1430146380000,1430194140000,1430236920000,1430283120000,1430326860000,1430371740000,1430416380000,1430460180000,1430505480000,1430548500000,1430594460000,1430636760000,1430683260000,1430725020000,1430772060000,1430813340000,1430860920000,1430901720000,1430949900000,1430990340000,1431039060000,1431079200000,1431128520000,1431168480000,1431218220000,1431258360000,1431308160000,1431349020000,1431398040000,1431440220000,1431487800000,1431531360000,1431577260000,1431622140000,1431666540000,1431712440000,1431755640000,1431802320000,1431844680000,1431891960000,1431933660000,1431981360000,1432022580000,1432070700000,1432111560000,1432159980000,1432200540000,1432249260000,1432289580000,1432338600000,1432378860000,1432428060000,1432468500000,1432517520000,1432558560000]}
```

Which appears to be valid JSON, but on the server, `req.body` is this:

```
{ '{"entries":': { '1430014800000,1430055600000,1430104620000,1430146380000,1430194140000,1430236920000,1430283120000,1430326860000,1430371740000,1430416380000,1430460180000,1430505480000,1430548500000,1430594460000,1430636760000,1430683260000,1430725020000,1430772060000,1430813340000,1430860920000,1430901720000,1430949900000,1430990340000,1431039060000,1431079200000,1431128520000,1431168480000,1431218220000,1431258360000,1431308160000,1431349020000,1431398040000,1431440220000,1431487800000,1431531360000,1431577260000,1431622140000,1431666540000,1431712440000,1431755640000,1431802320000,1431844680000,1431891960000,1431933660000,1431981360000,1432022580000,1432070700000,1432111560000,1432159980000,1432200540000,1432249260000,1432289580000,1432338600000,1432378860000,1432428060000,1432468500000,1432517520000,1432558560000]': '' } }
```

which is an object that's only key is `{"entries":` and the value for that key is an object that's only key is an array of timestamps that should be sent as the value to `entries`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To close out this question properly in StackOverflow, you should either post your own answer (and then accept it when StackOverflow allows you to) or delete your question.  This site does not encourage you to post the solution in your question.

Comment: Okay, I've created an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the module I'm using for making requests (superagent) automatically stringifies data, so the issue went away when I stopped stopped using `JSON.stringify`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue was that I was making the request from the front end using AngularJS, and the default POST format was set to url-encoded:

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.post = {'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'};
```

By default, it's set to 'application/json', so I just removed this line, after which the JSON then resolved correctly.